# jquery get initial selector behind filter

Tags: jquery, filter, selector

Given:

```
jQuery("input[id$=-purchaser-name]").
filter("[id*=-edit-]").
somefunction();
```

How would I go about finding the string of the first selector from somefunction() ?

Comment: Erm... can you elaborate it? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the deprecated `selector` property:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPmhf/)

```
$.fn.somefunction = function () {
    console.log(this.end().selector);
    return this;
};

jQuery("input[id$=-purchaser-name]").filter("[id*=-edit-]").somefunction();
```